# Extending WP_List_Table seems getting wrong with $this->get_columns() - what's wrong?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-list-table

I'm trying to implement an Admin Table for a [view page of a plugin of mine](https://github.com/nanodesigns/ad-zonia/blob/master/ad-view-page.php) by following the following tutorial:

- [**Create Native Admin Tables In WordPress The Right Way**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/03/native-admin-tables-wordpress/)
     by *Jeremy Desvaux de Marigny*
     SmashingMagazine.com

Here's how I extended the `WP_List_Table` class for my plugin. ([Code at Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/LSezik4P))

The problem is: it's not showing any Column or Row, only the Table Top and Bottom. I did `var_dump()` steps, and found that in **Line 149** the `var_dump($columns);` is showing empty.
[image: Extended List Table]

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG ABOUT THIS PORTION?

```
/* -- Register the Columns -- */
$columns = $this->get_columns();
$_wp_column_headers[$screen->id]=$columns;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This,

```
$_wp_column_headers[$screen->id]=$columns;
```

...is deprecated long ago. Instead you need to assign your columns to the following class property on `WP_List_Table`,

```
$this->_column_headers = array( 
    $this->get_columns(), 
    array(), //hidden columns if applicable 
    $this->get_sortable_columns()
);
```